# Split string and convert the substrings to integers in Go

Tags: string, variables, go, split, substring

I've got a single variable containing something like `1,2,3`. These are actually three values, that I want to have in three variables called `v1`, `v2`, `v3` (but **not** in an array).

Right now I'm doing this in the following way:

```
tmp := strings.Split(*w, ",")
sw, _ := strconv.Atoi(tmp[0])
rw, _ := strconv.Atoi(tmp[1])
pw, _ := strconv.Atoi(tmp[2])
```

This works, although it is very repetitive and does not *feel* right in Go.

What would be a cleaner way to solve this issue?

Comment: That's pretty well how you do it, tbh.  That said, if you're getting it in as a comma-separated list, why aren't you manipulated it as a slice of ints?  You could convert in a loop that way.  Seems like a code smell issue.  Also, don't ignore the error returns from `Aoti` (though you may have just been doing that to compact your example code).

Comment: If you want the results in local variables `sw`, `rw`, and `pw`, then this is the way to do it. If you want a slice of values, the code would be cleaner, but you wouldn't have your set of local variables with individual values.

Comment: @Kaedys Yes, i'm ignoring it only to keep it short. I'm writing a program and the interface is specified in the this way and out of scope, so I have to deal with this format. sw, rw, pw have a special meaning and it makes more sense to keep them separately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Parsing data out of a `string` with a specific format and storing the parsed values into variables is a perfect task for and is easily done using [`fmt.Sscanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf):

```
src := "1,2,3"

var a, b, c int

parsed, err := fmt.Sscanf(src, "%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c)
fmt.Println(parsed, err, a, b, c)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5OZZ2OU2tR)):

```
3 <nil> 1 2 3
```

#### Making it strict

As noted, this is very lenient, and will also successfully parse the `"1,2,3,"` and `"1,2,3,4"` inputs. This may or may not be a problem (depending on your case). If you want to make it strict, you can apply this little trick:

```
var temp int
parsed, err := fmt.Sscanf(src+",1", "%d,%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &temp)
```

What we do is we append one more of the numbers that matches the input. If the original input does not end with a number (such as `"1,2,3,"`), parsing will fail with a non-`nil` error, and the above example gives:

```
3 expected integer 1 2 3
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zRGXDaHMLv). Of course it will continue to parse "valid" inputs without any errors.

Note that this still accepts the input `"1,2,3,4"`. We can "reduce" this trick to a single character, and we don't necessarily need a "target" variable to store it, it may simply be designated by the format string, like in this example:

```
parsed, err := fmt.Sscanf(src+"~", "%d,%d,%d~", &a, &b, &c)
```

We append a special character *unlikely* to happen in the input, and we expect that special character in the format string. Attempting to parse an invalid input (such as `"1,2,3,"` or `"1,2,3,4"`) will result in an error such as:

```
3 input does not match format 1 2 3
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fyBQPnVfJC).

Comment: Seems like the cleanest solution, although it is very lenient. For instance `1,2,3,4` or `1,2,3,` is also recognized.

Comment: @KarolBabioch Yes, this may or may not be a problem. If you want it to be strict, see edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with a slice result, you could do it with slices:

```
tmp := strings.Split(*w, ",")
values := make([]int, 0, len(tmp))
for _, raw := range tmp {
    v, err := strconv.Atoi(raw)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        continue
    }
    values = append(values, v)
}
```

Working playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/Y-QHmHP8Iy

Comment: No, slices are not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use maps:

```
V = make(map[int]int)

// in cycle
for i :=1; i < 3; i ++ {
    V[i], _ = strconv.AtoI(tmp[i])
}
```

Comment: Or a slice.  Since a map[int]int is functionally identical to a slice, except less efficient.

Comment: Also the code is invalid, and sets each element of the map equal to its key, which doesn't seem to be what's desired.

Comment: @Adrian, code is not invalid :) - it’s an example how to deal with such values

Comment: Again, both versions are examples, first illustrates the principle. Second - usage. I’ve edited so people could easily understand.

Comment: I explicitly asked how to do this without slices ;).

Comment: Ok ) I’ve proposed to consider maps solution as they be useful when number of parameters grows and also keep semantics. If use like `map[string]int` like `V["sw"]`